# Why Non null values in Sparse columns takes extra space in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

May I know why Sparse columns which are having non null values takes 4Bytes of extra space..I am finding out why it is taking **4 bytes of extra space**.. Please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) (my bold)

> The SQL Server Database Engine uses
>   the SPARSE keyword in a column
>   definition to optimize the storage of
>   values in that column. **Therefore, when
>   the column value is NULL for any row
>   in the table, the values require no
>   storage.**

The reverse would be NON-null means "always store a value" = bytes used with the following condition:

> Sparse columns require more storage
>   space for nonnull values than the
>   space required for identical data that
>   is not marked SPARSE.

.. and the following table in MSDN shows +4 bytes per sparse column

Sorry if this sounds harsh, but what else would you expect?

[And a nice summary of SPARSE here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/andrew/archive/2008/02/28/sql-server-2008-sparse-columns.aspx)